# JavaFX how to get a list of events available for every class?

Tags: events, javafx, controls

Is there a way of getting a list of classes available in javafx.scene.control and the events of each one?

I would like to have in a table all the controls available in javafx (obviously those that come with it) and in another table all the events associated to each control.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/) and look at the list of properties defined for each class. Properties whose names being "on" represent event handlers, so indicate that the control (or other node) fires properties of the indicated type.

So for example, Button has an [`onAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#onActionProperty) property of type `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`, so you can register handlers for action events with it.

All properties (whether or not their name matches the onXXX pattern) represent observable properties with which you can register `ChangeListener`s or `InvalidationListener`s. So `Label` has a [`text`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textProperty) property with which you can register a `ChangeListener` that will be notified if the text changes.